# Find the subtree difference in Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I described the graph here on [gremlify](https://gremlify.com/zr4eawd2a3m). So I have four types of vertices: *Content*, *User*, *Group*, and *Video*. *Content* and *Group* serves as a container, *User* and *Video* are the leaves. Also, I have possible edges between a *Group* and a *User*, a *Group* and a *Content*, a *Group*, and a *Video*. *User* can also be assigned to a *Video* and *Content* directly. *Video* can be added to a *Content* vertex. I have to calculate the difference of the tree when *Content* drops from a *Group*. I created a query that traverses from *Content*, aggregates all directly assigned *Users*, and then subtracts those *Users* from *Group* members set:

```
g.V().has('ContentId', 1).in('Assigned').
  choose(label()).
  option('User', __.aggregate('DirectAssign')).
  option('Group', __.out('Added').where(without('DirectAssign')).
      as('ToDrop'))
      .select('ToDrop')
```

However, there are few drawbacks:

- I have doubts that the query is optimal from a scale and performance standpoint, as on 100k users in a group - it consumes almost all my RUs
- I need to calculate *Video* access for each user individually (not a big deal)
- I can't write this query in added ORM framework, as `aggregate` creates a new scope there and it's impossible to refer to that aggregated collection in the 2nd option step.

So my question is: is it possible to rewrite this query (keep it single) without the `choose` step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your use-case you can find those users by traversal back into the content. and therefore you could avoid `aggregate` and `choose` steps.

```
g.V().hasLabel('Content').
    as('content').
  in('Assigned').hasLabel('Group').out('Added').
  not(where(out('Assigned').
        as('content')))
```

example: https://gremlify.com/ozhf4t0xv4j

Comment: Works like a charm, perfect. Can you please explain this bit of magic with `as` at the end?

Comment: @vmeln `as` is not a regular step, and it behaving differently depending on the context he is in (similar to `by` step). inside of a `where` step instead of labeling the vertex, he compares it to the already labeled vertex. this is a common recipe in gremlin and you can find it in any cycle detection query